# Nested parameter expansion: Why is ${foo%"$bar"} legal, but ${$bar} not?

Tags: bash, shell

I'll start with the two motivating examples, to give proper context for the question, and then ask the question.  First consider this example:

```
$ ext=.mp3
$ fname=file.mp3
$ echo ${fname%"$ext"}
file
```

Evidently, in parsing `${fname%"$ext"}`, bash first expands `$ext` into `.mp3`, and then expands `${fname%.mp3}` into `file` — the last step follows trivially from the definition of `%` expansions.  What's confusing me is the expansion of `$ext`...

In particular, let's compare the above with this similar example:

```
$ a=value
$ b=a
$ echo ${$b}
-bash: ${$b}: bad substitution
```

Of course, I know I could use "indirect expansion" here to achieve what I want:

```
$ echo ${!b}
value
```

But that's not relevant to my question.  I want to understand the specific bash evaluation and parsing rules that explain why `${$b}` fails but `${fname%"$ext"}` succeeds.

The only relevant passage I've found in `man bash` is this:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

But I'm not seeing how the different behaviors result from these rules.

I'd like see an explanation that explains each step of the evaluation process of the two examples, and the rule underlying each step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look up `${parameter%word}` expansion in the [bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) you'll see that `parameter` and `word` are treated differently. `word` is subject to *pathname expansion* while `parameter` is not.

> ```
> ${parameter%word}
> ${parameter%%word}
> ```
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern. **The `word` is expanded to produce a
>   pattern just as in pathname expansion.** If the pattern matches a
>   trailing portion of the expanded value of `parameter`, then the result
>   of the expansion is the expanded value of `parameter` with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>   `%%` case) deleted. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If `parameter` is an array variable
>   subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to
>   each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list.

That seems like it would explain it. But it doesn't. *Pathname expansion* only means globbing and pattern matching with `*`, `?`, and the like. It doesn't include variable expansion.

The key is to read up. There's a preamble that applies to the above:

> In each of the cases below, **`word` is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.**

In totality, `word` is subject to *all* of these expansions. Key to this question: `$ext` is expanded via recursive *parameter expansion*.

I say "recursive" because it can in fact be nested arbitrarily deep. To wit:

```
$ echo ${fname%.mp3}
file
$ echo ${fname%"$ext"}
file
$ echo ${fname%"${ext%"$empty"}"}
file
$ echo ${fname%"${ext%"${empty%""}"}"}
file
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  So the recursion is the exception rather than the rule -- a special feature limited to a few specific sub-cases of parameter expansion.  Any idea why this is the case (ie, the design considerations motivating this)?

Comment: No, I don't. I don't know why `${$name}` isn't allowed. My guess is it's a consequence of history and I don't know much about how shell syntax evolved over time. Pure speculation: since `%` is a newer feature perhaps the shell designers were free to do fancy things, whereas they were constrained by history (the POSIX standard?) on the left-hand side.